# Scheme: Convert from Let to Lambda

Tags: function, lambda, scheme, let, chicken-scheme

so I'm trying to experiment with some code and change between the two scheme expression methods of **let** and **lambda**.

The code I have is as follows:

```
(let splice ((l '()) (m (car s)) (r (cdr s)))
        (append
          (map (lambda (x) (cons m x)) (perm (append l r)))
          (if (null? r) '()
        (splice (cons m l) (car r) (cdr r)))))
```

I'm trying to change the outermost **let** definitions to **lambda** format, but it's a bit confusing due to the nested nature of the code. What I have attempted to do so far is:

```
(lambda (splice (l m r))
        (append
            (map (lambda (x) (cons m x)) (perm (append l r)))
            (if (null? r) '()
    (cut (cons m l) (car r) (cdr r)))))
(('()) (car upList) (cdr upList))
```

This is clearly wrong, but I don't know how to proceed further...

Comment: You’re almost right: since lambdas do not have names, your args list is wrong (it should be `(lambda (l m r) ...)`), and you need to assign it to a binding, probably with `letrec`. Then you want to invoke it using that name, passing it the initial arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out! What about the inner block such as `(splice (cons m l) (car r) (cdr r))` where the let definitions are used recursively? Will those work with the binded lambda or will that need to be modified further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote [a post about how `let` is transformed into `lambda` behind the scenes](http://qr.ae/RUymgf), which you may find helpful.

According to the expansion described in my post, your code would expand into:

```
((rec (splice l m r)
   (append (map (lambda (x) (cons m x)) (perm (append l r)))
           (if (null? r)
               '()
               (splice (cons m l) (car r) (cdr r)))))
 '() (car s) (cdr s))
```

which then expands to:

```
((letrec ((splice (lambda (l m r)
                    (append (map (lambda (x) (cons m x)) (perm (append l r)))
                            (if (null? r)
                                '()
                                (splice (cons m l) (car r) (cdr r)))))))
   splice)
 '() (car s) (cdr s))
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the way the expansion is handled. Thank you also @AlexisKing for clarifying my doubts about the transformation syntax :)